# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, numpy

For the following code, I am getting the error I have put in title:

```
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np

temp = np.load('temp.npy')
sio.savemat('final.mat',temp)
```

Although `AttributeError` is a common error in python, I did not find anything useful for `'items'` as mentioned in the title. How can we fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It takes a dict as the second argument not an array:

From the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html):

**mdict : dict**

> Dictionary from which to save matfile variables.

I am not overly familiar but I imagine you pass the name as the key and the array as the value, something like:

```
sio.savemat('final.mat',{"foo":temp})
```

Comment: Thanks! Do we have to convert arrays to dictionaries in order to save them as .mat file?

Comment: @A.M., as far as I can tell you pass a string as the key and the array as the value. There are other keywords that affect how the array is stored

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue as follow:

```
from scipy.io import savemat
import numpy as np
num= np.arange(20)
mymat={'num':num}
savemat('mymat.mat', mymat)
```